# C++ - Can you assume type* = std::array<type>::iterator?

Tags: c++

I think it is easier to just show this in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct Test
{};

int main()
{
    std::array<Test, 1> arr {};
    Test* t = arr.begin();
}
```

arr.begin() returns a iterator but as you can see I can refer to it with Test*. This seems to be possible due to implicit cast, can I expect this to work across other compilers as well according to the standard?

Also is it the operator TYPE that does the implicit cast, ex:

```
operator T*()
{
    return &(*this->CONTAINER)[index];
}

template <typename U>
operator U() = delete;
```

or something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [The C++ standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequences#array.overview-3) an `iterator` is *implementation-defined*:

> `using iterator               = implementation-defined; // see [container.requirements]`

*[container.requirements]* says that `iterator` should [be at least](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements):

> Any iterator category that meets the forward iterator requirements.
>   convertible to X::const_iterator.

Neither [requirements of a forward iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) nor the requirements of the [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) (ForwardIterator needs to satisfy requirements for InputIterator) nor the requirements of an [Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) (InputIterator needs to satisfy requirements for Iterator) state that they should have this conversion operator and thus this is very compiler specific and not standard.

Comment: **−1** Re the last para that (the OP's hypothesized) conversion operator is not required and "is very compiler specific", on the contrary, there is no such operator, and an implementation that provides one is not standard-conforming.

Comment: s/is not standard-conforming/is probably not standard-conforming/. It seems I would have a hard time proving that claim. But since having such operator would conflict directly with the purpose of having non-pointer iterator, I can't believe that one would find it in *any* real implementation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Fit? No, I agree. Could it be that OP's implementation has one? Yes it could. It doesn't directly make the implementation not standard conforming. I doubt OP made his own conversion operator but rather uses the one provided by the implementation.

Comment: @BillGates: There is no conversion operator. g++ `std::array` uses raw pointers as iterators.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Nobody said anything about what compiler OP was using. Might not be g++.

Comment: Well, the burden of proof is on you: find a **concrete example**. Just as you would need a concrete example for a claim that gigabyte `bool` can be encountered (it's technically allowed). Here is code you can use in your search: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c570439364e106e5

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question was "*can I expect this to work across other compilers as well according to the standard?*" I answered that question. It's implementation defined.

Comment: This is working on clang 3.8 and g++ 6.2.1 on fedora 24 x64. I haven't changed anything whatsoever. You can run it here as well: http://cpp.sh/3fjl6

Answer (score 2):

[`std::array::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin) returns an `iterator`, not a `pointer`.

The `iterator` *can* be defined as a pointer, but it doesn't need to be.

To get a pointer to first item you can use [`std::array::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data).

---

Re the “implicit cast”, no, there's no such here.

---

A general technique for converting an iterator to raw pointer is to first derefence it, `*it`, which generally yields a reference, and then take the address of that, `&*it`. However, this will necessarily fail when there is no addressable item to take the address of, such as in a packed `std::vector<bool>` (it's up to the implementation whether it's packed, but *if* it's packed). In such a case dereferencing the iterator yields some proxy object instead of a raw reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation defined: C++14 Standard § 23.3.2.1 numeral 3. Your code works on GCC, but you cannot make that assumption across compilers.